# JsonPath expression to filter on an attribute and select a partial record?

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

Here are the details about what I am using:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
  <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I have the following example JSON.

```json
[
    {
        "something": "who cares",
        "job_name":"my-long-job-name-that-ends-in-box",
        "some_number": 1
    },
    {
        "something": "who care here either",
        "job_name": "my-long-job-name-that-ends-in-something-else",
        "some_number": 2
    }
]
```

So far I can match a record that ends in `box`:

```
$.[?(@.job_name =~ /^.+box/i )]
```

finds all the objects that have `job_name` ending in `box` and dumps out the entire record. This is ok, but I would like to specify a subset of attributes to return instead of the entire object sometimes.

In my real data there are dozens of fields, I only really need to see a few of them at a time.

`$.[?(@.job_name =~ /^.+box/i )].job_number` will only return the `job_number`.

Using the example data above how would return `job_name` and `some_number` but not `something`?

#### How would I modify my `JsonPath` expression to return just the fields that I want to see.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

After some more trial and error with the documentation and one more thing I had not tried yet I found the solution:

```
$.[?(@.job_name =~ /^.+box/i )].['job_name','some_number']
```

will return a `Map` with only the `job_name` and `some_number`as keys for only the one record in the example data.